# How to fix null pointer exception issue in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm running jenkins build job which takes code from git and builds an artifact
but I'm getting following error

```
 Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
 ERROR: Asynchronous execution failure
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:992)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:986)
    at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:55)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuilder.waitForAsynchronousExecutions(AbstractMavenBuilder.java:186)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:146)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You must explain the issue with more details. I hope with just the exception details no one can provide a solution

Comment: I am also facing this curious issue, there is no error to share as it builds as well as deploys successfully. We would also like to get rid of this issue. It could be related to java version conflicts between the ` jenkins slave` , `maven` and your `sourcecode` .